# unable to preserve border format on range.insert

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to insert a new row while preserving the border format?  I am able to insert while preserving all formatting except for borders.  The macro that I am creating will essentially prompt the user for a value (strXX) then search for it in a list.  If it does not exist, the following is executed.

```
iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(strXX, Columns("A")) + 1
Intersect(Range("Z:TT"), Rows(iRow)).Insert _
XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Is there something that I must change with respect to the **CopyOrigin**?  There appears to be methods available via the Paste functions, however I am not able to find a similar method when using .Insert.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated...Thanks!

**Updated (8/15):**
Since this post, I have reformatted things in my spreadsheet and am able to work around the issue.  I am still very much interested in feedback as the original configuration was not able to copy the border.  This will surely resurface at a later date.  Please see below for supporting info.

There are 2 sheets that will be updated.  The 1st works well as it preserves the cell formatting (no border required).  See below.
[image]

The issue described in this posting relates to the second sheet.  The row is inserted and all formatting is preserved except for the borders (standard "Outside Borders" setting).  See below.
[image]

Comment: can you show any screen shot of the range presenting (by selection) where you want to insert new row? in my opinion there are no borders fully set around your inserting area, that is the result. are they standard borders or some sophisticated?

Comment: Hi KazJaw.  I have a response ready with screenshots however, it won't let me submit as I don't have enough reputation points to submit :(  Let me see if there is an alternate way to accomplish the screenshots.  Thx!

Comment: @KazJaw - I do not see an option to post screenshots due to my reputation points.  The rows above/below the inserted item contain a standard 'Outside Borders' border. The new row contains the 'vertical' border, however it lacks the horizontal border above the new row.

Comment: you could upload your file or screenshot anywhere in the Internet. Next, add link to that file to comment here or to your question.

Comment: @KazJaw - please see updates in the post as I am now able to upload screenshots.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't repeat your problem but I think I have seen that somewhere before. AFAIR, the reason is the way you applied your borders before inserting row- top border, bottom border or mid border (I check all but insertion works fine, Excel 2010). My suggestion is be to apply borders as a next step right after row insertion. So, you will need quite simple code which I think you can do on your own (or with a little help from macro recorder). Moreover, you could ask on SuperUser.Com what is the reason that your border are not showing as expected.

Comment: Thanks KazJaw.  I will experiment a bit with the borders in my macro as a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with code as suggested in the comments, something like this

```
With cell.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
   .LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .ColorIndex = 0
   .TintAndShade = 0
   .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cell.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
   .LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .ColorIndex = 0
   .TintAndShade = 0
   .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cell.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
   .LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .ColorIndex = 0
   .TintAndShade = 0
   .Weight = xlThin
End With
With cell.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
   .LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .ColorIndex = 0
   .TintAndShade = 0
   .Weight = xlThin
End With
```